# How to point an IP address to domain name

Tags: server, ip, remote-access

I have an IP address of a server (http://185.207.xxx.xxx/test2.php) and I want to open this as (http://domainname.com/test2.php) from my system.

when i edited my hosts file in /etc/hosts with following entry

> ```
> 185.207.xxx.xxx  domainname.com
> ```

but it is showing below error:

> ```
>  Error: The requested URL can not be retrieved
> ```

Can anyone help me in resolving this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this , 
   `185.207.xxx.xxx domainname`

Not need to add `.com`
and the hosts file must be edited as the Administrator or root user. In Windows, remember to open your text editor as the Administrator user.

Comment: I tried with `domainname/test2.php` and `domainname.com/test2.php` both but showing ` Error: The requested URL can not be retrieved`. I have added same as 185.207.xxx.xxx domainname in /etc/hosts file. What i need to do ?

Comment: Is this IP , hosted with another alias name in the hosts file?

Comment: which server you are using?

Comment: i am using nginix dedicated server. I have tried in linux and windows both in my local machine